# Usage of "onto' and "into" with materials

Tags: differences, word-usage

I have a sentence which means **"to use a laser to transfer an image from the computer and have it be imprinted on any material; wood, plastic, glass, metal, anything else"** What is the correct way I should say this?

- To imprint an image **onto** the material?
- To imprint an image **into** the material?

Or maybe there is some other way? Maybe with words: transfer, apply, put, embed.

I should ask as well, Is there a big difference between the two when we speak about merging two object?

- Squeeze the ink **into** the water?

or

- Squeeze the ink **onto** the water?

Answer (score 1):

Evidence from [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=transfer%20an%20image%20onto%2Ctransfer%20an%20image%20into&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctransfer%20an%20image%20onto%3B%2Cc0) suggests that "onto"  is more commonly used in "transfer an image".

The idea is to transfer/print  an image ***on (to) a surface***, plastic, wood, glass etc. not into.

Comment: Please give me more information about the other questions. I wish to know then why is it embed in - meaning to apply onto a surface? To embed a photo in a stone.

Comment: On(to) refers to the surface of water, In (to)   means underwater.

Comment: Okay. So when we say "Squeeze the ink into the water?" we mean place something inside the water/go through the surface and then squeeze the ink? And when we say "Squeeze the ink onto the water?" we mean place something over the surface/above it and then squeeze the ink?

Comment: If you put you hand on the water you keep your hand on the surface. If you put your hand into the water you push your hand  past the surface, into it. Please refer to the  older question for more  exemples.